# No such Table Sqlite JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc

Yo guys. The problem I'm facing is pretty weird..
I am creating a table at first, then trying to put data on it, but for somereason something is ticking off. It says

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: Name)
```

Aaand here's my basic code..

```
try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                  conni  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//Asus//Dropbox//TireShop.sqlite");


                  stmt = conni.createStatement();

                  String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + project.getText() + " (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , Name TEXT, One TEXT, Two TEXT)";


                  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                  stmt.close();
                  conni.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
                  System.exit(0);

            }
            try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                  conni  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//Asus//Dropbox//TireShop.sqlite");

                  String query1 = "insert into Name (Name) values(?)";
                  PreparedStatement pst = conni.prepareStatement(query1);
                  pst.setString(1, project.getText());
                  pst.execute();
                  pst.close();
                  conni.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
                  System.exit(0);


            }
            try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                  conni  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//Asus//Dropbox//TireShop.sqlite");

                  String query1 = "insert into " + project.getText() + "(Name, One, Two) values(?,?,?)";
                  PreparedStatement pst = conni.prepareStatement(query1);
                  pst.setString(1, project.getText());
                  pst.setString(2, textField_one.getText());
                  pst.setString(3, textFieldtwo.getText());
                  pst.execute();
                  pst.close();
                  conni.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
                  System.exit(0);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you");
```

Thank you for the help! I really can understand... I guess the table is not being created at all, but it actually worked once. So It gets me even more confused o.o

Comment: Wich is the value of `project.getText()`? In your code you use both `project.getText()` and the string "Name". Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` is a [MySql reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Rename the table to something else.

Comment: That actually helped alot mate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please encase your fieldnames with `"` to escape them.

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE \"" + project.getText() + "\" (\"Id\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , \"Name\" TEXT, \"One\" TEXT, \"Two\" TEXT)";

 String query1 = "insert into \"Name\" (\"Name\") values(?)";

 String query1 = "insert into \"" + project.getText() + "\" (\"Name\", \"One\", \"Two\") values(?,?,?)";
```

Also... I'm assuming you've patched together these code snippets from various points in your code..

But i advice you to set up a SINGULAR database connection in your code and to reuse that connection throughout your application.
Something along the lines of:

```
public class MyApp {
     public static Connection DB;
     public void initDatabase() {
         try {
             MyApp.DB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//Asus//Dropbox//TireShop.sqlite");
          }
          catch(Exception ex) {
          }
     }
     public static void main(String args[]) {  
         MyApp app = new MyApp();
         app.initDatabase();
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course because you're not using a reserved name anymore, but this is just good practise. Just as you ident your code with tabs or spaces, place brackets at the same locations, you should **always** encase fieldnames, no matter the db engine.

Comment: Good, it will help preventing a lot of future bugs :-)